# Compiling dbd:sybase on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perl, compilation, perl-module

I am trying to compile dbd:sybase module(DBD-Sybase-1.07) in 64 bit perl(5.12.3). However, I am getting following error messages on doing so on doing nmake. Please let me know what am I missing.

```
Creating library blib\arch\auto\DBD\Sybase\Sybase.lib and object blib\arch\au
to\DBD\Sybase\Sybase.exp
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blk_rowxfer
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_send_data
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blk_init
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_cancel
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cs_diag
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_results
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cs_ctx_alloc
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_connect
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cs_dt_crack
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_bind
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_options
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_callback
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_cmd_drop
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_close
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blk_bind
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blk_drop
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cs_loc_drop
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cs_locale
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_param
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blk_props
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blk_done
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cs_ctx_drop
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_send
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_con_drop
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_get_data
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_con_props
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cs_config
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_config
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_res_info
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_compute_info
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_dynamic
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_init
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blk_describe
dbdimp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ct_cmd_alloc
blib\arch\auto\DBD\Sybase\Sybase.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 44 unresolved extern
als
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'E:\BuildTools\i\win32\Microsoft\VisualStudio\2010\VC
\BIN\amd64\link.EXE' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Sybase client libraries, along with their associated header files.

Comment: I have header files under "E:\Sybase\OCS-15_0\include" and my SYBASE variable is set as e:\sybase. Its not able to pick the header files

Comment: Your `%SYBASE%` environment variable must point to a directory with (at least) two subdirectories: `include` and `dll`. Yours points to a directory containing `OCS-15_0` instead.